# How to find the formula for simple harmonic motion given some data?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, physics

> The frequency of oscillation of a mass attached to a spring is 3.0 Hz. At
> time t = 0, the mass has an initial displacement of 0.20 m and an initial velocity of 4.0 m/s.
> What is the position of the mass as a function of time?

we are given the amplitude, I found the angular frequency this way:

$$f = 3$$
$$T = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$\omega = \frac{2\pi}{1/3} = 6 \pi$$
the formula for the moment is this
$$x = 0.20  \cos(6\pi t)$$
I am missing the phase shift and also if a I take the derivate of x at time t is not 4 how can complete this eq?

update the answer was using the formula that express x in terms of his initial vel and position

$$0.20 cos(6\pi t )+ \frac{4}{6\pi}sin(6\pi t)$$

Comment: If $x=A\cos(\omega t)$, then $dx/dt=-\omega A\sin(\omega t)$ which vanishes at $t=0$. So $x=A\cos(\omega t)$ can only describe an oscillation which starts at rest. This is why the phase shift is needed...

Comment: @Semiclassical that's correct my question is how to find the phase shift?

Comment: Use a formula which includes the (unknown) phase shift, then compute the initial values $x(0)$, $v(0)$ and solve for the unknown.

Comment: thank you I found the formula for x in terms of x_o and v_o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking for an answer, then *an* answer is
$$x(t)=\sqrt{x_0^2 + \frac{v_0^2}{\omega^2}}\cos\left(\omega t-\arctan\left(\frac{v_0}{\omega x_0}\right)\right)$$
where $x(0)=x_0$ and $\dot{x}(0)=v_0$ and the frequency $\omega=\sqrt{k/m}$ is the natural frequency of the mass-spring system. Let me know if you want me to show how to derive the equation.

Comment: is that formula the same as this? $$0.20 cos(6\pi t )+ \frac{4}{6\pi}sin(6\pi t)$$

Comment: I found that one using the equation of x expressed in terms of the initial condition is that what you did.

Comment: Indeed, they are equivalent

Comment: I am having trouble finding the turning point using the point at which the slope is zero here is the continuation https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4706023/1177689