# How to find all the solutions for $ -\frac{6\pi}{5}\sin(6\pi t) + 4\cos(6\pi t) = 0$

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry

Let's say we have this function of velocity, I usually calculate the turning point by setting the parameter of sin equal to pi but this time I have cosine how would you find the turning point I see it is when the slope is cero is there any other way to find it?

$$v = -\frac{6\pi}{5}\sin(6\pi t) + 4\cos(6\pi t) = 0$$
$$4\cos(6\pi t) = \frac{6\pi}{5}\sin(6\pi t) $$
$$\frac{\cos(6\pi t)}{\sin(6\pi t)} = \frac{6}{20}\pi$$
$$\cot(6\pi t ) =  \frac{6}{20}\pi$$
$$t = \frac{\cot^{-1}((6/20)\pi)}{6\pi} = 0.72$$

This is not the desired turning point how can I find all turning points? Or here is a second idea:

$$\frac{10\cos(6\pi t)}{3\pi \sin(6\pi t)} = 0$$
since the denominator can't be $0$ hence the numerator must be $0$ hence the whole family of solutions is when the numerator is $0$ is this correct?

Comment: the family of solution of that tan function I think that's the key

Comment: Can you explain the step when you went from $\cos ( 6 \pi t) / \sin ( 6 \pi t)$ to $ arctan ( 6 \pi t)$? Why are those equal?

Comment: @CalvinLin thats the inverse of tangent

Comment: Do you want "the (functional) inverse of tangent", or do you want "the (reciprocal) inverse of tan x"? Are these two the same? Note that inverse has a lot of meanings.

Comment: is that equivalent to the arctan or tan^-1?

Comment: what is cosx/sinx?  arctan or tan^-1

Comment: That's a great question for you to answer for yourself. For me, I prefer to say that cos x / sin x = cot x, to avoid this potential confusion. $\quad$ You are saying that cos x/ sin x  = arc tan x $\Rightarrow \tan ( \cos x / \sin x ) = x$

Comment: @CalvinLin now that the notation issue is solved how would you find all the turning points of that function?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the notational error. Can you follow through the rest of the proof and fix the mistakes from there?

Comment: @CalvinLin seems like 0.72 is not a turning point 0.709 is one of them

Comment: See my solution for what it means to fix the error through the rest of the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $\tan x=a$, then $x=\arctan (a)+k\pi, k\in\mathbb{Z}$. In your case, since time $t$ is non-negative usually, we have

$$6\pi t =  \arctan\left(\frac{20}{6\pi}\right)+k\pi,~~~k=0, 1,2\dots$$

Solve for $t$, we get

$$t =  \frac{1}{6\pi }\arctan\left(\frac{10}{3\pi}\right)+\frac{k}6,~~~k=0, 1,2\dots$$

Plug in $k=0$, you get the first turning point:

$$\frac{1}{6\pi }\arctan\left(\frac{10}{3\pi}\right)=0.0432372$$

Comment: first turning point is 0.043 plug in o  for k I don't get 0.043

Comment: You need to use inverse trig function "$\arctan$", NOT "$\tan$"

Comment: -1 I'm guessing that you took OP's erroneous work and ran with it. I'm not sure why you got upvotes for that.

Comment: See my comments to the post, or my solution.  $\quad$ Ah, no, your error might be saying that $\cos x / \sin  x = \tan x$ instead of cot x.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{6\pi }\arctan\left(\frac{10}{3\pi}\right)=0.0432372$$ @CalvinLin

Comment: Right, you fixed the error after editing. You previously quoted $\arctan(6 \pi t ) = 6/20 \pi $, when it should have been $\cot ( 6 \pi t) = 6/20 \pi$, which I got OP to fix. $\quad$ My point still stands that the first 2 upvotes you got before the massive edit didn't make any sense. $\quad$ I have undone my downvote.

Comment: That should be a typo for the OP

Comment: I don't understand why is arctan on the right. ? why not cot^-1

Comment: Because $\tan(\theta)=\frac{1}{\cot\theta}$, I use $10/3\pi$, you use $3\pi/10$ @SirMrpirateroberts

Comment: In general, if tanx=a
, then x=arctan(a)+kπ,k can you elaborate more on that one? I would like to understand how that relates to turning points

Comment: Turning point is a physical concept, such as you run forward, when you turn back, that's the turning point, which means your velocity at turning point is zero. After you set $v=0$, it is converted into a pure math problem on how to solve a trig equation. You can find some trigonometry textbook on how to solve trig equations, such as, how to(and why) find solution families for trig equations. The most common ones are how to solve $\sin x=a, \cos x=a, \tan x=a$ @SirMrpirateroberts

Comment: @MathFail I see that trig function have infinitly many solutions whats the algorithm you use in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Technique 1.

Use calculus, take the derivative and set it equal to zero.

$v(t) = -\frac {6\pi}{5}\sin (6\pi t) + 4\cos (6\pi t)\\
v'(t) = 6\pi (-\frac{6\pi^2}{6}\cos (6\pi t) - 4\sin (6\pi t)) = 0$

Simplify and solve for $t.$

$-\frac {3\pi}{10} = \tan(6\pi t)\\
t = \frac {1}{6\pi}(-\arctan(\frac {3\pi}{10})) + \frac {n}{6}$

Technique 2.

$a\sin x + b\cos x$
$\sqrt {a^2+ b^2} ( \frac {a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \sin x + \frac {b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \cos x)$

Let $\phi = \arctan \frac {a}{b}$
$\sin \phi = \frac {a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\\
\cos \phi = \frac {b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$

$\sqrt {a^2+ b^2} ( \sin \phi \sin x + \cos\phi \cos x)\\
\sqrt {a^2+ b^2} (\cos (x-\phi))$

And find the turning points as you know how to do.

Comment: what did I get wrong when I solve for t in my question?

Comment: you are differntiating twice I already give the function differentiated

Comment: i am looking for the first turning point 0.043

Answer (score 1):

OP made a mistake in their work. I got them to correct the step to $\cot ( 6 \pi t ) = \frac{6}{20} \pi $, but they didn't fix the last line which is still wrong.

Working from the corrected step, we get

$$ 6 \pi t = \pi n + \cot^{-1} \frac{ 3 \pi  } { 10 } $$

Finally, substituting in $n = 0 $, we do get $ t = 0.043$ from [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=cot+%286+pi+t%29+%3D+6%2F20+pi)

[image]